# SOQL Performance With LIMIT 1

Tags: soql, query, governorlimits, performance

I became accustomed to add a `LIMIT 1` clause at the end of my SOQL request when I want to request only one record. Even when I don't declare an array as result.
For example:

```
Account account = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = 'Example' LIMIT 1];
```

It's just a habit.
I was thinking that this was more precise and so maybe faster.

So I wanted to know if there was a way to see if there is an impact in terms of perfomance.

Comment: @DanJones I agree that it's the same question, though our answers are quite different. Not that there's anything wrong with that! I think the vote makes sense.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Don't get me wrong, I'm not "defending my answer" or anything silly like that. :) I just remembered answering a similar question in the past is all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the case of assignment to a single record and filtering on an Id, there is zero impact on your governor usage. It won't affect CPU Time, and if you were already enforcing exactly one result by assigning to a single record, it won't affect heap size or query rows either. Obviously it won't affect number of queries. I can't think of any other relevant governors here.

In regards to CPU Time, note from [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) (emphasis mine):

> CPU time is calculated for all executions on the Salesforce application servers occurring in one Apex transaction. CPU time is calculated for the executing Apex code, and for any processes that are called from this code, such as package code and workflows. CPU time is private for a transaction and is isolated from other transactions. Operations that don’t consume application server CPU time aren’t counted toward CPU time. For example, **the portion of execution time spent in the database for DML, SOQL, and SOSL isn’t counted, nor is waiting time for Apex callouts.**

---

In terms of the **[`Query Plan`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&type=1)**, there is no impact either, to `Cardinality` nor `Cost`. Note that only the most efficient plan is used, so while there is a curious third plan evaluated when you add the `LIMIT` clause, it does not effect run-time performance of the query.

**Filter On Id, No Limit**

- Cardinality: 1
- Cost: 0.00005636343140570398
- Screenshot:

  [image: Id Filter No Limit]

**Filter On Id, With Limit**

- Cardinality: 1
- Cost: 0.000056363431140570398
- Screenshot:

**Filter On Name, No Limit**

- Cardinality: 1
- Cost: 0.00016909029421711193
- Screenshot:

  [image: Name Filter No Limit]

**Filter On Name, With Limit**

- Cardinality: 1
- Cost: 0.00016909029421711193
- Screenshot:

  [image: Name Filter With Limit]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry I don't really understand how it can be possible that DML statements don't impact CPU time. It must impact something no? Also, if the filter wasn't on the id, could it be useful?

Comment: @MartinLezer Well, if you write a filter that could return thousands of records, and then you add `LIMIT 1`, of course it can affect query rows, heap size, etc.

Comment: Yes but imagine I have this query: Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Example']. And I know I have only one record like this. This is just an example. My question will be: Does Salesforce stop searching for another account because of the variable declared which is not an array, or Salesforce needs the 'LIMIT 1' clause to be faster?

Comment: Wow thanks for the time you spent to answer my question. I guess I have to change my habits...

Comment: No it's not a bad thing. It's protective if, for instance, you're wrong that there is only one record with that name.